Is there a dagesh in the kuf of קמנו?
I have seen different versions of the second-last posuk in Tehillim 20: ואנחנו קמנו ונתעודד. Some have the kuf with a dagesh (קַּמְנוּ). Others have the kuf without a dagesh (קַמְנוּ). The Minchas Shai doesn't mention this difference in girso. What is behind this difference?

Where have you seen it without the dagesh?

The Leningrad Codex has it with a dagesh. The page in the Aleppo codex containing this פרק is, unfortunately, currently lost.

The Aleppo Codex page is unfortunately lost as noted by @Qwertrl in the comments. Edition of Keter Yerushalaim produced by R. Breuer, based on existing 15 old manuscripts  and 16 classical reference works, has dagesh. The Nusach haMikra notes supporting Keter Yerushalaim on this particular word are absent in recording any differences. I.e. all agree that there should be a dagesh. Tanach Simanim and Tanach ArtScroll have dagesh as they are likely following this opinion. So does The New Concordance of the Hebrew Bible by Abraham ibn Shoshan.
The Leningrad Codex edition as Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia has dagesh. However the Massora on the bottom has a comment sic L, mlt Mss Edd קַ, i.e. such is the Leningrad codex manuscript, but multiple other edited manuscripts do not have dagesh. The Leningrad codex edition of Aharon Dothan has dagesh and no variants in the back.
The Mikraos Gedolos edition of Machon haMaor does not have dagesh. Neither does edition of ArtScroll Tehilim. It seems this opinion is based on the European manuscripts collected by the Bomberg publishing House and included in the study by C.D. Ginsburg. The C.D. Ginsburg edition of The Masorah v. 4, p. 522 from year 1905 does not have dagesh in this word. The list of the manuscripts that he used is described in Chapter 12 of his book "Introduction to the Massoretico-Critical Edition of the Hebrew Bible", pp. 469-778. It describes 60 manuscripts. The author does not disclose the manuscript differences, and his list of manuscripts includes the Leningrad / St.Petersburg Codex.

Ginsburg lists the manuscripts in his edition: https://ibb.co/RzN9v35.
